# Infinity value in evaluation step

Tags: matlab, depth, infinity

I estimated a depth map using machine learning and i want to evaluate my results (using matlab). Depth map and depth true are images with 8 bits (normalized to [0 1] before evaluation). I used relative,rmse and log 10 error to do the step of evaluation.

```
function result = evaluate(estimated,depthTrue,number)
  if(number == 1)
     result = relative(estimated,depthTrue);
  end
  if (number == 2)
      result = log10error(estimated,depthTrue);
  end
  if(number ==3)
      result = rmse(estimated,depthTrue);
  end
end




function result = relative(estimated,depthTrue)
  result = mean(mean(abs(estimated - depthTrue)./depthTrue));
end

function result = log10error(estimated,depthTrue)
  result = mean(mean(abs(log10(estimated) - log10(depthTrue))));
end

function result = rmse(estimated,depthTrue)
  result = sqrt(mean(mean(abs(estimated - depthTrue).^2)));
end
```

When i try an evaluation with image i got infinity value (only log10error and relative). After search, i found that depthTrue and estimated  can have 0 values.

```
log10(0)

ans =

  -Inf
5/0

ans =

   Inf
```

So, what should  i do ?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several approaches to overcome this, depends on what best suits your needs. you can ignore the `inf`'s or just replace them with other values. for example:

```
depthTrue = rand(4);
estimated = rand(4);
estimated(1,1) = 0;
% 1) ignore infs
absdiff = abs(log10(estimated(:)) - log10(depthTrue(:)));
result1 = mean( absdiff(~isinf(absdiff)) )
% 2) subtitute infs
veryHighNumber = 1e5;
absdiff(isinf(absdiff)) = veryHighNumber; 
result2 = mean( absdiff )
% 3) subtitute zeros
verySmallNumber = 1e-5;
depthTrue(depthTrue == 0) = verySmallNumber;
estimated(estimated == 0) = verySmallNumber;
absdiff = abs(log10(estimated(:)) - log10(depthTrue(:)));
result3 = mean( absdiff )
```

Comment: thnx sir, i found the solution i used the values with meters (0 not exist).